# JavaFX how to change background color of tableview column using CSS?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, scenebuilder

With javafx scene builder I hava created a TableView with few editable columns and few non-editable columns. How to set CSS style for non-editable columns, so that the entire column is greyed out.
I have created a style class like below and mapped it to table column in javafx scene builder. But it didn't work.

```
.greyout1 .table-column-cell{
-fx-background-color:rgb(243,243,243);
-fx-border-color:rgb(159,159,159);
}
```

Searched the forum, could n't find a solution for styling tableview columns.Could you please suggest an approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this and its perfectly worked...

```
      email.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<CheckDo, String>, TableCell<CheckDo, String>>() {

        @Override
        public TableCell<CheckDo, String> call(TableColumn<CheckDo, String> p) {


             return new TableCell<CheckDo, String>() {

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!isEmpty()) {
                    this.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
                    setText(item);
                }
            }
        };
```